# How does doppler shift makes any sense?

Tags: doppler-effect

Consider this. The reason we see red at dusk is because the sun is away from us, and thus the wave length is longer, which corresponds to the color red.

But think of a transmission line that is over your head. The transmission line carries 60 Hz  no matter how far away you are from the generator. If I were to measure the voltage right at the generator, it is 60 Hz, if I were to measure it a mile away, it is still 60 Hz. There is no shift.

Can someone clarify for me why there maybe a discrepancy?

Comment: The reason we see a red sky and redder Sun at dusk is the same reason we see a blue sky at noon. The answer lies in the atmosphere, not because the Sun is away from us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason we see red at sunset doesn't have anything to do with the Doppler shift of light; if it did we wouldn't see reddened skies at dawn, and the old rhyme

> Red sky in morning,
>   sailor take warning;
>   red sky at night
>   sailor's delight

would be silly impossible nonsense instead an actual useful rule-of-thumb guide to the weather.  The sun appears reddened when it is low in the sky because the atmosphere preferentially scatters away the blue light to make blue skies elsewhere; looking through the thickest part of the atmosphere the remaining sunlight is blue-depleted, with reduced intensity and a reddish bias.

The Doppler shift in light between two observers moving with relative velocity $v=\beta c$ is a ratio between the observed frequency $f$ and original frequency $f_0$ of
$$
f = f_0 \sqrt\frac{1-\beta}{1+\beta}
\approx f_0 \cdot (1 -\beta + \cdots)
$$
where the approximation is good for nonrelativistic $\beta$, such as the rotation of the earth. I'll leave it to you to compare the rotational speed of the Earth (about 1000 mph at the equator) to the speed of light and decide just how much frequency shift to expect; it's pretty hard to measure.

Comment: So there would be a doppler effect if we take our voltmeter and rush towards the generator?

Comment: @Math Newb - Yes, you would be moving towards each successive peak of the waveform as seen by an observer at rest on the ground, so the time between successive peaks would be less for you then for the ground observer.

Answer (score 1):

Doppler shift is a function of relative velocity, not distance; the sun is the same distance from us at dusk as it is at noon. Another case of Doppler shift you're probably familiar with us passing vehicles. The horn, siren, engine, etc. of a vehicle passing you will sound higher as the vehicle approaches and lower as it goes away from you. A stationary car will sound the same pitch whether you're far away or nearby.

The sky is red at dusk and dawn because of Raleigh scattering, not Doppler shift, which does technically happen at dusk and dawn but on a scale far too small to distinguish with the naked eye.

It's interesting that you mention the 60Hz power lines; that's frequency of the alternating current in the line, not the power of the current. Since the apparent frequency is what is altered by Doppler shift, if you were to measure the frequency of the current alternation while traveling toward or away from the line, you'd notice a difference in the apparent frequency based on your velocity relative to the line.

Comment: Actually the distance between an observer and the sun changes by [about 40 parts per million](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=radius+of+earth+in+astronomical+units&hl=en&gbv=1) between noon and dusk, which is about thirty times bigger than the [Doppler frequency shift](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=1000%20mph%20divided%20by%20speed%20of%20light) for an observer at the equator.